# How to round a google timestamp to next midnight or noon

Tags: javascript, datetime, timestamp

I have a google timestamp return date: "2019-04-01T14:12:22.223Z"

I want to convert this timestamp to the nearest midnight or noon(0:00:00 OR 12:00:00) depending on supplied timestamp.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Nothing, because I cannot seem to figure out the google timestamp format... I think it is UTC? but I am unsure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The format returned by Google is UTC. You could "normalize" the date and round it to either 0:00 or 12:00 by checking in what range the current hour is.

```js
function normalizeTime(UTCDate){
    var nomalized = new Date(UTCDate);

    nomalized.setHours(
        nomalized.getHours()+1 >= 6 && nomalized.getHours()+1 < 18 ? 12 : 0
    );
    
    nomalized.setMinutes(0);
    nomalized.setSeconds(0);
    nomalized.setMilliseconds(0);
    
    return String(nomalized);
}

console.log(normalizeTime("2019-04-01T02:12:22.223Z"));
console.log(normalizeTime("2019-04-01T14:12:22.223Z"));
console.log(normalizeTime("2019-04-01T20:12:22.223Z"));
```

Comment: Thanks this is exactly what I was looking for.